# Is it normal not to be able to reuse a variable obtained from a connect()?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I made a login page and I'm trying to retrieve the name of the user who logged in and then display it in the next page and to adjust my program according to the person logged in.

But I desperately run into the same problem, I can't extract the variable from the slot to reuse it and do everything I have to do with it :(
So I wonder if it's a specificity of the slot (I start Qt and I don't know much about it) or if I'm the one who doesn't do things correctly.

PS: I've obviously read and reread the Qt documentation about this but it doesn't help too much.

My code:

glybook.cpp (where I want to put the login information)

```
#include "ui_glybook.h"

glybook::glybook(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::glybook)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //qDebug() << receiveConnectionData(username);
    test();
}

void glybook::receiveConnectionData(QString name){
    username = name;
    //qDebug() << username;
    ui->label->setText("Connected: "+username);
}

void glybook::test(){

    qDebug() << ui->label->text();
}

glybook::~glybook()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

glybook.h

```
class Glybook;
}

class Glybook : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Glybook(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Glybook();

    void test();

private slots:
    void receiveConnectionData(QString);

private:
    Ui::Glybook *ui;

    QString username;
};
```

connection.cpp (login page)

```
#include "./ui_connection.h"

Connection::Connection(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Connection)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Connection::~Connection()
{
delete ui;
}

void Connection::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

QString user =  ui->lineEdit->text();
QString pass = ui->lineEdit_2->text();

glybook* page = new glybook();

connect(this, SIGNAL(sendConnectData(QString)), page, SLOT(receiveConnectionData(QString)));

emit sendConnectData(user);
page->show();
this->close();
}
```

connection.h

```
#define CONNECTION_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include "glybook.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Connection; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Connection : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Connection(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Connection();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

signals:
    void sendConnectData(QString);

private:
    Ui::Connection *ui;
};
#endif // CONNECTION_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Connection w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: *I can't extract the variable from the slot to reuse it and do everything I have to do with it* Please explain this in details.

Comment: I want to store the name of the user who logged in in a variable outside the slot and then retrieve (put it in a User object) and display the account information on the glybook.cpp page. To detail, let's say I have all my account information on a database, and I access it by making a query with the username and then display it in bulk on my page. But I would like to do this outside the slot function of glybook.cpp. Is this possible?

Comment: It's is not an answer on my question in the comment. What is *"I can't extract the variable from the slot to reuse it"*. What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: In void Glybook::receiveConnectionData(QString name) the username value is the username of the username but when I display username out of receiveConnectionData it doesn't display anything so that's why I say "I can't extract the variable from the slot to reuse it"

What I want is to be able to use username outside of the slot function and have it show me the same thing as it did in the slot function.

Comment: I don't understand why username doesn't take the value of name outside the function when I assigned name to username, it doesn't make sense :(

Comment: In other words, I expected to have the value of the username stored in the username variable even outside the slot function; But it's only in this function that it takes the value entered in the login page.

Comment: Agreed, it does not have sense. The code provided is not enough, please make [mcve]. Maybe `username` is reset from elsewhere, or you use another instance of Glybook, or you call `test()` before the signal has been delivered.

Comment: edited my first post, still get the same error but this time i got the ancient name of the text label, so maybe test is called too soon, but i don't know where to call it otherwise

Comment: @S.M. Have you had time to watch my program? Have you had time to watch my program? I'm stuck on it and it's starting to annoy me, I've tried a thousand and one ways and still nothing, it's a harmless thing to transfer data from one page to another yet, why is it so difficult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cause

You call the `test` method of `glybook` in its constructor, which is executed as a result of this line:

```
glybook* page = new glybook();
```

At that time neither the  connection

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(sendConnectData(QString)), page, SLOT(receiveConnectionData(QString)));
```

is made, nor the signal `sendConnectData` is emitted, so your `qDebug() << ui->label->text();` prints an empty `QString`.

## Solution

If you want to see the value sent by `Connection` in `glybook`, check it AFTER the execution of the `receiveConnectionData` slot.

That being said, I highly suggest you to read about Object Oriented Programming, as well as to go through a well known Qt course by VoidRealms on Youtube.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's very helpful. But where could I put the ```test()```? Except in the constructor who starts anyway before the signal? Would there be a way to launch the slot before the constructor? I mean, as soon as I initialize glybook for ```connect()```, it will necessarily launch with its constructor before the slot, right?

Comment: And if I do ```connect(this, &connection::sendConnectData, page, &glybook::receiveConnectData)``` without initializing page (so that the constructor doesn't start before), it won't launch, of course.

Comment: _Would there be a way to launch the slot before the constructor?_ Can you start breathing bevore you are born? Or doing anything for that matter?

Comment: In your example, when you show `glybook`, the slot is already executed. Why do you need the username earlier? If you really insist to use the username, preserving your current setup, reimplement [QWidget::showEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#showEvent) and call the `test` there. You will indeed get the username, but I highly doubt, that this is what you really want to do.

Comment: ```test()``` is used to see if the ```username``` has taken the value of the previously entered username. I think ```username``` is useful because I need to display this name everywhere in my program, I would have to go through the slot each time I want to get the value of the name otherwise

Comment: Change `explicit Glybook(QWidget *parent = nullptr);` to `explicit Glybook(const QString &name, QWidget *parent = nullptr);`, `glybook::glybook(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::glybook)` to `glybook::glybook(const QString &name, QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::glybook), username(name)` and `glybook* page = new glybook();` to `glybook* page = new glybook(user);` You would be surprised.